# Submitting form through modal with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I had created website that has modal through which i can submit form using ajax. I am not very good with jquery and javascript so i need some help cause things are not working so well.

This is my form code in modal body. Here everything works fine as i can see.

```
<form action="inc/queries.php" method="post" class="insert-movie">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputTitle" id="InputTitle" placeholder="Enter title">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="year">Year</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="InputYear" id="InputYear" placeholder="Year">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="year">Duration</label>
        <input type="time" class="form-control" name="InputDuration" id="InputDuration" placeholder="Duration">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="year">Gender</label></br>
        <select name="InputGender">

            <?php
            $pdo = connect();
            // display the list of all members in table view
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM zanr";
            $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            $list = $query->fetchAll();      

            foreach ($list as $rs) {
            ?>  
            echo'   
            <option name="InputGender" value="<?php echo $rs['id'] ?>"><?php echo $rs['naziv'] ?> </option>'

            <?php } ?>
        echo'   
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="year">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="InputDescription" placeholder="Description" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image upload</label>
        <input type="file" id="InputImage">
        <p class="help-block">Select image of movie.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
  </div>

  </form>
```

This is javascript code:

```
$('.insert-movie').on('submit', function() {
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    method = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
}); 

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
return false;
```

});

and last, code that manipulates given variables and inserts into database.

```
<?php
 include 'config.php';
  if(isset($_POST['InputTitle'], $_POST['InputYear'],      $_POST['InputDuration'], $_POST['InputDescription'], $_POST['InputGender'])) {   
$pdo = connect();
$InputTitle       = $_POST['InputTitle'];
$InputYear        = $_POST['InputYear'];
$InputDuration    = $_POST['InputDuration'];
$InputDescription = $_POST['InputDescription'];
$InputGender      = $_POST['InputGender'];

$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO filmovi(naslov,godina,trajanje,opis,id_zanr) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5)");
$sql->execute(array(':field1' => $InputTitle, ':field2' => $InputYear, ':field3' => $InputDuration, ':field4' => $InputDescription, ':field5' => $InputGender));
$affected_rows = $sql->rowCount();
```

}

What is the problem, problem is when i open modal and enter data. I press submit and it takes me on query.php page witch is empty, in another words it isn't working properly. Data from form are stored in DB but something is wrong and i don't know what.

Comment: You're not preventing the default behavior of the submit.

Comment: Is that my only problem or? How can i fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have type: type, which is an error.

Change to:

```
$('.insert-movie').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    method = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
}); 

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: It is working now, thank you! Can you just tell me what i need to do if i want to upload images to. I now the php part but js not.

Comment: That will be another issue! Best google 'jquery ajax image upload' as there are different methods to it - and depends how you get the image (and depends on the browser)

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of the submit event -

```
$('.insert-movie').on('submit', function(event) { // pass the event to the function
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action, keeping the browser on the same page
```

Comment: I did that and now it stays on the same page but now it does not save data in db

Comment: Did you watch the request / response in the browser console to see if everything was sent properly?

Comment: As i can see, nothing is sending. It only display this : "type is not defined" for js

Comment: You have to correct the JavaScript errors

Comment: sry but i don't know how to fix this problem, do you think that is the problem i can't submit

Comment: You need to learn basic JavaScript troubleshooting and repair.